# How to redirect to login screen if not logged in for certain web pages

Tags: asp.net, forms, web, web-config, forms-authentication

So I have a login.aspx and it is set up so that all forms redirect to the login page if you are not logged in. This site is suppose to be public, no login is required except if you are admin and want to access special admin pages. How do I make it so that if someone tries to access a page only for admin they get sent to the login page.

```
     <authentication mode="Forms">
       <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" protection="All" defaultUrl="login.spx">
       </forms>
      </authentication>
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
   </authorization>
```

Comment: This is not classic asp, this is ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to make a folder for the admin pages, in that folder store your admins aspx page and add a web.config with similar entries that you have, so if someone tries to request a page in that folder asp.net will take them to login to first, before asp.net processes the request.